# How to evalute string of IP address in c#

Tags: c#, split, ip-address

Now I have a series of addresses with the format "\10.4.1.2\Camera_save". They are in total 18, the only number varies is the 3rd number in the IP address (e.g: 10.4.2.2, 10.4.3.2.....10.4.18.2)
What I need to do is extract the 3rd number from an address, any idea?
P.s The addresses are in an array with 18 elements. I have another array trams[] for storing the extracted 18 numbers.

Ok what I tried is to use string.replace(), like

```
      directory[i].Fullname.Replace('\\10.4.','').Replace('.2\Camera_save','');
```

The error says the arguments for Replace() are too long and null string is not OK. Since I got this method from another post where the replace() was used exactly like this. So any explanation?

Comment: Split by delimiter '\', then split second match by '.'

Comment: Maybe you have already tried something? What is your exact problem - unexpected results or some error?

Comment: This site was not designed to complete your tasks or do your homework. Show us your efforts, what have you tried to accomplish your task?

Comment: Sounds like X-Y problem.

Comment: OK guys, Andy showed a perfect solution!

Comment: OK fine. i did sth like: "directory[i].Fullname.Replace('\\10.4.','').Replace('.2\Camera_save','');"   And I got the error saying that the arguments I used in Replace() are too long, and the empty string is not OK to use. Maybe somebody could tell me why it is? since I got this method from another post

Comment: @jcraffael Did you already fix it?

Comment: @Andy Yes I did, with your solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] ip = { @"\10.4.1.2\Camera_save", @"\10.4.5.2\Camera_save" };
String[] result = ip.Select(x => x.Split('.')[2]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string with `Uri.Parse`, pick the first segment, then parse it like IP address with `IPAddress.Parse` and then convert them to 4-byte array using the `.GetAddressBytes()` and pick your third byte.

Comment: A bit complicated. But anyway thanks for the reply and probably it would be helpful for the future!

Comment: @jcraffael It is the only right way to do. Of course you might pick your IP segment by `string.Split` or even by an indexer, but this is very bad practive, unless it`s your homework.

Answer (score -1):

you can `Split()` by `.`:

```
string number= ip.Split('.')[2];
```